# How to update a page's content using SPServices?

Tags: sharepoint, spservices

I am trying to update a Page's content using SPServices.

When I run my code, it does update the correct page, but instead of updating the content, it just removes the content.

```
var newContent = "<p>This is a test</p>";

$().SPServices({
   operation: "UpdateListItems",
   listName: "Pages",
   ID: itemID,
   async: false,
   valuepairs: [["PublishingPageContent", newContent]]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs since `UpdateListItems` operation expects HTML *escaped* string as a a parameter.

The following function could be used for encoding HTML string:

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
  //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/1375553)

**Fixed example**

```
var itemID = <Your item id goes here>;
var newContent = "<p>Some content goes here</p>";
$().SPServices({
   operation: "UpdateListItems",
   listName: "Pages",
   ID: itemID,
   async: false,
   valuepairs: [["PublishingPageContent", htmlEncode(newContent)]],
   completefunc: function(xData, Status)
   {
         console.log('Page has been updated');      
   }
});
```